# html javascript calculation

Tags: javascript, html

code for get value by HTML input then calculate 11% from that value. after that value + main input value. ex- enter 200 as main value 200/100*11 = 22 . then again collect main value 200 + 22 = 222 (final answer)

Comment: please help me. programmers

Comment: This is not a way to ask question..first format it properly and make us understand what you exactly need

Comment: You should show you have made some effort yourself.  SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @i.mihiran first try your self something. If any issues exists then we all free to help you anytime.

Comment: <html>
 <head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function cal() {
     var inputValue = Number(document.getElementById('val1').value);
     var  calculatedAmount = inputValue/100*11;
     var totalValue = inputValue+calculatedAmount;
     document.write(totalValue)    
} </script>

 </head> 

<body> <input type="button" onclick="cal ()" > <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/> 

</body> 

</html>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use the following function

```
    function cal() {
     var inputValue = Number(document.getElementById('val1').value);
     var  calculatedAmount = inputValue/100*11;
     var totalValue = inputValue+calculatedAmount;
     document.write(Math.round(totalValue))    
}
```

Comment: Requiring jQuery for such a simple task is completely unnecessary and overkill, since it's an ID use `document.getElementById('#inputId')` instead and simply use `value` as an attribute instead of a function to get the field value to do this without jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I am so used to jquery that it skipped my mind

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function cal (){ 

var x = document.getElementById('val1').value; 
var z = 11/100*x;  
document.write(z);

  
}
</script>
</head>
<body onmouseout="cal ()" >
<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/> 

</body>
</html>

Comment: i.mihiran add it to your question

Comment: No problem. Please try to format your questions properly next time to avoid downvotes by the community :

Comment: after get final value as 506.16999999999997 . i want get last 2 point num as 506.16 and last number check . if >=5 then answer 506.20 . if there 506.14 last num < 5 answer must be 506.10. how can do this?

Comment: '<html>
 <head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function cal() {
     var inputValue = Number(document.getElementById('val1').value);
     var  calculatedAmount = inputValue/100*11;
     var totalValue = inputValue+calculatedAmount;
     document.write(totalValue)    
} </script>

 </head> 

<body onmouseout="cal ()" > <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/> 

</body> 

</html>'

Comment: round the value as Math.round()

Answer (score 1):

To get value of an input field in javascript:

```
var mainvalue = document.getelementbyid('id of your input field').value;
```

Then calculate the 11 % of the main value:

```
var per = mainvalue/100*11 ;
```

Calculate the Final answer:

```
var finalanswer = mainvalue + per ;
```

Comment: <html> <head> <script type="text/javascript"> function cal (){ var x = document.getElementById('val1').value; var z = 11/100*x; document.write(z); } </script> </head> <body onmouseout="cal ()" > <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/> </body> </html>

Answer (score 0):

From your code I assume that you may b want like following

```js
$('input').on('mouseout', function() {
  var x = document.getElementById('val1').value;
  var z = 11 / 100 * x;
var a=parseFloat(x) +parseFloat(z);
  alert(a.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" />
```

Comment: ex- if enter 456 answer must 506.20